# Check WCF Service without creating client proxy

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, ping

I want to test whether wcf endpoint is reachable or not. Only available data is URI address to the service.

Can I connect to service to check whether it exist without creating the Client Proxy of service?

EDIT: I want to achieve this programmatically, i.e. make a Method like this:

```
bool EndpointReachable(UriAddress)
```

My service might be bound using the net tcp binding

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve? In the same way that you shouldn't check　a file exists before you delete, you shouldn't check a service exists before you use it - just use it and then handle the failure.